# Reactjs application using CDNs without any installations

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to print the output on chrome, but I am able to print the output on other broswers. Secondly, I have made use of CDNs namely react and JSXtransformer. Can anyone suggest how to proceed.

Comment: You have to show us some code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with simple html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

          ReactDOM.render(
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('root')
          );

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```